How to calculate AUC-ROC for multiclassSummary in caret?
Here is my code. Is this the correct way to calculate AUC-ROC for a multiclass problem?
train_ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 3, repeats = 3,
                           summaryFunction = multiClassSummary, classProbs = TRUE,
                           savePredictions = TRUE)

fit_svmPoly <- train(winner ~ ., data = data_train,
                      method = "svmPoly",
                      trControl = train_ctrl,
                      tuneGrid = tune_grid_poly,
                      metric="AUC")


You should show results. I would expect that an AUC would not be an appropriate measure of predictive accuracy since AUC is defined in terms of binary outcomes.
